# Unable to send a message to Discord using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to simply create a function that sends a discord message to a specific channel when the bot runs. I want to later call this function in a separate python script.
The code below seems to run fine, and the bot appears online - but it is fails to send the message:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
client.run("ABCDeFGHIjklMNOP.QrSTuV-HIjklMNOP") # the token

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    logs_channel = client.get_channel(12345689123456789) # the channel ID
    await logs_channel.send("Bot is up and running")
on_ready()
```

I'm sure I'm missing something basic but I cannot figure out what it is. I've tried a similar function in Node.js and it works fine however, I would prefer the bot to work in python. Discord.py is up to date, python is v3.10.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Client.run` is a blocking call, meaning that events registered after you call it won't actually be registered. Try calling `Client.run` after you register the event, as in:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    logs_channel = client.get_channel(12345689123456789) # the channel ID
    await logs_channel.send("Bot is up and running")

client.run("ABCDeFGHIjklMNOP.QrSTuV-HIjklMNOP") # the token
```

You also probably do not want to be manually calling an event handler. If you want to send a message by calling a function, you probably want to consider writing a separate function to the event handler.